# cakephp 3 and fpdf cannot render pdf in form of a view

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, fpdf

```
**Controller**                  : Test
**View where the form resides** : index.ctp
**View containing fpdf code**   : pdf.ctp
```

I generate a pdf file using FPDF but the pdf file is not rendering properly. I have confirmed that the FPDF code is error free.

On URL

```
localhost/project/test
```

I will fill up a form and press submit. This will submit to

```
localhost/project/test/pdf
```

But here the pdf is not rendering properly. It just keeps on telling Loading.

If i submit it to some other folder/pdf.php file (same fpdf code in php file)
Everything is ok

```
localhost/fpdf/pdf.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my questions myself. Come on people HELP ME!!

The problem was that the output was not rendering as pdf. I used this controller to solve my problem.

```
public function pdf()
{
    $this->response->type('pdf');
}
```